# Running a simple logic app with repeat over a list takes a long time

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a simple Logic App with one HTTP GET connector that returns a JSON list and two actions: one HTTP POST and one Office365 that repeat over the same list returned in the HTTP GET action.

This is app logic workflow:

[image: Logic App Workflow]

Consistently (several attempts) the workflow takes a really long time. I am only returning 15 items:

[image: Workflow Run Time]

The 8 minute run is when I have both the HTTP POST and Office365 connectors and the 5 minute runs is when I only have the HTTP POST. Also....running the Office365 alone runs for about 5 minutes.

Isn't this a little too much?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the limits on the App Service plan used for your Logic App. Various limits apply depending on the tier of the App Service plan. Once the limits are reached, operations of all logic apps under the App Service plan will be throttled resulting in slow execution times.

For free/shared/standard plans, you are only guaranteed 200 executions per day.

Please check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/ for details.

You can inspect the App Service plan on the Essentials panel of your logic app in the Azure portal.

[Where to find details of App Service plan for a Logic App in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4EXG.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I am not nearly close to any throttling limits. My service plan is basic small. I still have no answer to this. I also posted the question to MSDN forum and has gotten a little more response: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ba3a53a5-a1a2-488a-b479-f94d7d63baf0/what-makes-a-logic-app-run-so-slowly?forum=azurelogicapps&prof=required

Comment: @Khaled, remember that what counts towards throttling limits is each operation of your logic app (i.e. each runtime operation, so an action could effectively be counted as multiple operations depending on how it is defined). This is especially evident in case of repeat actions, which you use in your definition. You mention that you have two actions that get repeated over 15 items - this would count as 30 operations towards the quota per each run. Any retries due to intermittent errors, as well as do-until executions would count extra as well.